# Why Niobium-titanium is used for superconducting magnets in MRI, accelerators and fusion reactors

Tags: superconductivity

Does someone have an idea why in Wendelstein 7X, ITER and in CERN Niobium-titanium is preferred over recent alloys. Some high-temperature super conductors have critical fields over 100 Tesla and niobium-titanium has just 15 Tesla. Consequently, the efficiency of such devices is more than an order of magnitude worse than theoretically possible, especially if one considers that the max plasma pressure is not linearly increasing with the field strength. However, I guess that I miss something as people working is these field will probably know all this.

Comment: Because they need industrial scale production of the alloys and magnets. Somebody's fancy new alloy they make in a university lab takes a great deal of time and money to scale up to the many tons needed for real magnets in a real machine.

Comment: Is there really no market demand? I mean the potential market for fusion reactors would be unlimited. I think, MRI would also profit from this.

Comment: Yes, there is market demand - all the current machines had to assess the state of the art and make engineering decisions about what the best magnets they could get for construction were. You don't wave a magic wand and have multi-ton magnets appear on your loading dock at the right moment. Further, critical field is only one parameter of interest - you have to try to optimize on many parameters. (Note that to a real business, the future scenario of unlimited fusion reactors is so far off as to be a fantasy, not a business decision.)

Comment: These two comics strips—[xkcd](https://xkcd.com/683/) and [smbc](http://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/exact-science)—are about 'science' but the same issue comes up with the popular perception of engineering of a lab operation into a product. Going from lab-bench to production is hard, expensive and time consuming.

Comment: I don't think that the critical field of the superconductor is the only consideration. I believe that another major parameter is the yield strength of the alloy since the high magnetic fields put a lot of mechanical stress on the superconductor coils. An Nb-Ti alloy probably has a lot more strength than pure Nb or the high-Tc superconductors you're thinking of.

Comment: I think it would be interesting to find something about the problems in manufacturing conductor stripes out of different Type 2 conductors.